# IPC with MINIX3

Tags: c++, ipc, minix

I'm trying to compare Inter Process Communication in Minix3 and Lubuntu, using c++. Is that possible considering different architectures and libraries needed for IPC, can someone give some tips how to achieve this? Thanks!